# How to get names based on it roles

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way  to display two person name in same row based on their role. 
I having 4 tables which is person, student, teacher and TourAttend. Person is the parent of the two table student and teacher.

```
Person
-------
personID 
Name 
Role

Student 
--------
StudentID 
personID reference person

Teacher 
-------
teacherID
personID reference person

TourAttend
-----------
 TourID reference to Tour table (Which i didnt reveal)
 TourAttendID primary key
 PersonID  reference person
```

example values of

```
 PersonID | Name    | Role
 -----------------------
     1    | student1| student
     2    | student2| student
     3    | teacher1| teacher
     4    | teacher2| teacher
     5    | student3| student
```

example values for TourAttend

```
    TourID | tourAttend | PersonID 
       1   |    1       |    1 
       1   |    2       |    2
       1   |    3       |    3 
       2   |    4       |    4 
       2   |    5       |    5
```

i would to get a query result that is each student is accompanied by who (teacher) Based on the Tour

```
 Student Name | Teacher Name 
   student 1  | teacher 1
   student 2  | teacher 1
   student 3  | teacher 2
```

so far i only tried is

```
    select person.name as 'student name' , person.name as 'Teacher name' from person
```

and i am stuck because the person.name is used for both. how do i resolve this problem?

Comment: Your database is not normalize. You have column `role` so you don't need table `Student` and `Teacher`, and you need 1 more table, usually it should be `class(classid, personid)` or something like that so we could know in your expected result it will be  `student 1 | teacher 1` or `student 1 | teacher 2`

Comment: @PhamX.Bach yes indeed, i have the table that is similar like that. However, the problem is how do i get the two person.name in same row based on roles

Comment: In case you have table `class(classid, personid)` then you could some join and get two column name from them. Like `select t1.name as student_name, t2.name as teacher_name from (...) t1 inner join (...) t2....`

Comment: `hiboss` could you update your question and show the table that we can know which student connected to which teacher?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach ok , I've updated the table and my requirement to make it more clear

Comment: For your `example values for TourAttend`, person 5 should be connected to person 4: `student 3 - teacher 2` ?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach Yes correct. my mistake on the value. update it now

Comment: Your example tables do not contain explicit information about which teacher acompanies which student on a given tour BUT if you assume that only 1 teacher was present in each tour you can calculate it by joining tables: TourAttend, Person and then LEFT JOINING Teacher and Student tables to Person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
select 
    t1.name as student_name, t2.name as teacher_name 
from
    (
        select
            p.name, t.TourID
        from 
            Person p
        inner join
            TourAttend t
        on
            p.PersonID = t.PersonID
        where
            p.role = 'student'
    ) t1
inner join
    (
        select 
            p1.name, t3.TourID
        from 
            Person p1
        inner join
            TourAttend t3
        on
            p1.PersonID = t3.PersonID
        where
            p1.role = 'teacher'
    ) t2
on
    t1.TourID = t2.TourID;
```